# Beginner - I can´t get my html to show images

Tags: html, image

I am practicing html coding, but whenever I try to use images I just get a broken link. I tried different sources for the images but I cant seem to get round this issue.

Thanks a lot!

Batman is a DC hero. Robin is his sidekick and he looks like a bat.

```
    <div>
      <img src=¨https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3666/12888758323_866b391f9a_b¨></p>
    </div><br>
    <div>
      <p>Spiderman has 3 main strong suits.</p>
      <ol>
        <li>He can climb super super super well.</li>
        <li>He can shoot sticky stuff. </li>
        <img src=¨https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spiderman/images/9/9c/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_129.1_Sin_texto.png/revision/latest?cb=20190317173958&path-prefix=es¨></p>
```

Comment: Make sure you're using standard quotation marks `"` in your image links. Yours look like this `¨`. Probably from copying and pasting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked!

Answer (score 0):

U must Add jpg to your src link

https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3666/12888758323_866b391f9a_b.jpg <-- .jpg